# How to hover over an image using capybara and selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, automation, capybara

Ive been trying to write an automation test to hover over an image using just capybara and selenium. Once i can get it to hover over the image i would like to check that the image has changed ie through the background image using the css. After some research some people have been saying that the trigger method doesnt work with selenium so ive been trying different stuff like:

```
hover = driver.find_element(:css => "element")
  driver.move_to.(hover).perform

featured_promo = page.find(:xpath, '//*[@id = "btnCalendar"]')
  featured_promo.native.hover()
```

Both of these have not worked.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
driver.mouse.move_to(hover)
```

Comment: code wise we have this - 
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
requestid = 'requestemployee' + request1_id 
hover = driver.find_element(:id => requestid)
driver.mouse.move_to(hover)
and we get the following error from it
Failure/Error: hover = driver.find_element(:id => requestid)
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError:
Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"requestemployee326"}

Answer (score 1):

Referring to this page: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html
Your code should look probably like below:

```
element = driver.find_element(...)
driver.action.move_to(element).perform
```

Comment: Hello Pawel, ive tried doing that but im getting an error saying NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `driver' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x5108d48>. Any suggestions on why im getting that error.

Comment: Have you created this driver object?
Please look here: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver.html
First you need create WebDriver object to work with selenium.
Pawel

Comment: As you may have guessed im pretty new to this. Ive created the driver object now but the only thing is it wont find the element but should be able to get that working. Thanks for your help Pawel!

Comment: First you can look here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/116-selenium. I'm using CSS selector to select an element and I'm using script from this page: http://www.selectorgadget.com/. You can see how this plugin works here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri. Some time ago I decided to leave selenium plugin and configure whole env manually with selenium server. Selenium server and selenium webdriver is my way to run selenium tests. Please look to Selenium API and Selenium page for more information how to run selenium server.